# Calling ajax on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to call ajax on the same page without click event, I am getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in index.php on line

It works fine with the click event. I am trying to do it without any events. My goal is to pass JavaScript variable to PHP.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          alert('est123');
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'index.php',
              data: ({name:"test"}),
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                  $('#results').html(data);
              } 
          })
          return false;
      });
</script>

</head>
  <body>
      <a href='#' class="idname">click me!</a>
      <div id="results"></div>
      <div><?php echo $_POST['name'] ?></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use a separate page to handle data, otherwise you may need a bunch of conditions. I recommend sending post data to PHP, which should `echo json_encode($assocArray);` back to your AJAX `success` method.

Comment: Try just `data: { name:"test" }`. I am not a jQuery expert (or javascript for that matter) but I have not seen brackets around the object on the `data` part of the `$.ajax` like you have it in any jQuery documentation....though again...no expert!!! I maybe wrong and learn something new.

Comment: @PHPglue +1@ seperate page. what would $assocArray be for?

Comment: You would put a PHP Associative Array in there after using something like `MySQL` with `PDO` or `mysqli` to get data from a database. After `echo json_encode($assocArray);` *(which happens after data is sent by JavaScript to that page)* that data should come back as JSON, through the argument sent to your `success` method, as long as your jQuery AJAX function's `dataType` property is set to `'JSON'`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it exists before outputting it

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name'] }
```

BUT I do not think this is what you want to happen since you will be sticking the HTML document returned into the page.

Comment: thank you but this is not what i am looking for, the problem is that $_POST['name'] is not set, but it being called when the page loads @eepascarello

Comment: Of course it is not set when the page loads.... There was no post made to the page when it is loaded. The code will run....

Comment: any suggestions how to fix it @epascarello

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The code will run when the page loads, I suggested that you check to see if the post data is there. If you do not want it to run, why is the code there and why are you posting back to the same page. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: i am trying to pass JavaScript variable to PHP, when the page loads

Comment: Do you realize that the PHP code has finished loading before the JavaScript code runs? There is no way for the JavaScript and php to run at the same time when the page is rendering.

Comment: is there another way ?

Comment: Yes, use Ajax the correct way. Create a php that does what you want, post data to it. Return what you want and set returned data with the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          dataArray={name:"test"};
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'index.php',
              data: dataArray,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data){
                  $('#results').html(data);
                  $('#lblName').html(dataArray.name);
              } 
          })
          return false;
      });
</script>

</head>
  <body>
      <a href='#' class="idname">click me!</a>
      <div id="results"></div>
      <div id="lblName"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```